# Merge arrays from unknown keys in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Given the following document:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "unknownkey1": {
      "subunknownkey1": [
        { "value": "somevalue", "dateReceived": ISODate("2020-07-15T12:01:00.000+0000") },
        { "value": "somevalue2", "dateReceived": ISODate("2020-07-15T12:00:00.000+0000") }
      ],
      "subunknownkey2": [
        { "value": "anothervalue", "dateReceived": ISODate("2020-07-15T12:00:00.000+0000") }
      ]
    },
    "unknownkey2": {
      "subunknownkey1": [
        { "value": "somevalue3", "dateReceived": ISODate("2020-07-15T12:05:00.000+0000") },
        { "value": "somevalue4", "dateReceived": ISODate("2020-07-15T12:06:00.000+0000") }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Keeping in mind that the key's with "unknown" mean that those key names **will not be known to me ahead of time**, I want to end up with a document that gets rid of the higher level "unknownkey*" level and has the array elements of matching "subunknownkey*" arrays merged together with the ultimate goal of getting the most recent "value" by "dateReceived" for each "subunknownkey*" but the last part is easy (I THINK) once I have the merged arrays.

Desired Result using above document input:

```
{
  "subunknownkey1": [
    { "value": "somevalue", "dateReceived": ISODate("2020-07-15T12:01:00.000+0000") },
    { "value": "somevalue2", "dateReceived": ISODate("2020-07-15T12:00:00.000+0000") },
    { "value": "somevalue3", "dateReceived": ISODate("2020-07-15T12:05:00.000+0000") },
    { "value": "somevalue4", "dateReceived": ISODate("2020-07-15T12:06:00.000+0000") }
  ],
  "subunknownkey2": [
    { "value": "anothervalue", "dateReceived": ISODate("2020-07-15T12:00:00.000+0000") }
  ]
}
```

I have tried working through a few pipeline stages using combinations of $unwind, $objectToArray, and $arrayToObject but I have not been able to quite get there.

Comment: How much filtering do you need to do on the DB side?   If the majority of the material needs to get to the client, just do `find()` and use code on the client to deal with it.   There's no need to stress the DB engine just to align the data in the shape you seek.

Comment: @BuzzMoschetti I fully agree and have been considering this but I think for my needs right now, having it occur on the DB side is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces almost the desired output.  Without a second doc to prove out the pipeline, this may not agg across unknown keys in 2 or more input docs.  Someone please find a slicker solution with less `$unwind`.

```
c = db.foo.aggregate([
{$project: {XX: {$objectToArray: "$properties"}}}

,{$unwind: "$XX"} // get rid of level 1 (unknownkey n)....                                                 

,{$group: {_id: "$XX.v"}}

,{$project: {WW: {$objectToArray: "$_id"}}}

,{$unwind: "$WW"}
,{$unwind: "$WW.v"}

,{$group: {_id: "$WW.k", items: {$push: "$WW.v"} }}

                      ]);
```

yields:

```
{
    "_id" : "subunknownkey2",
    "items" : [
        {
            "value" : "anothervalue",
            "dateReceived" : ISODate("2020-07-15T12:00:00Z")
        }
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : "subunknownkey1",
    "items" : [
        {
            "value" : "somevalue",
            "dateReceived" : ISODate("2020-07-15T12:01:00Z")
        },
        {
            "value" : "somevalue2",
            "dateReceived" : ISODate("2020-07-15T12:00:00Z")
        },
        {
            "value" : "somevalue3",
            "dateReceived" : ISODate("2020-07-15T12:05:00Z")
        },
        {
            "value" : "somevalue4",
            "dateReceived" : ISODate("2020-07-15T12:06:00Z")
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This appears to work perfectly, thanks so much! I was close but didn't get the groupings correct.